# Hierarchical data PHP combobox

Tags: php

This code works fine with the data bellow. But the Result is an Unordered lis and I would need it as a Dropdown Combobox. Does anyone nows How to do it with the SQL data and stucture in the post?

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `catid` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `catparent` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `catorder` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `catdesc` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`catid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `categories`
--

INSERT INTO `categories` (`catid`, `catname`, `catparent`, `catorder`, `catdesc`) VALUES
(1, 'Informática', 0, 1000, 'Computadores e acessórios'),
(2, 'Comunicações', 0, 1000, 'Sistemas de Comunicações'),
(3, 'Acessórios', 1, 2000, 'Acessórios para Computadores'),
(4, 'PABX', 2, 2000, 'Centrais telefónicas IP e TDM'),
(5, 'Controle de Acessos', 0, 1000, 'Controle de Acessos e Assiduidade'),
(6, 'Construção Civil', 0, 1000, 'Construçao Civil    ');
```

Code

```
  <?php
  include '../lib/configuration.php';

  $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $database);

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
  {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
  }

  $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
  if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) 
  {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    { 
      $arrayCategories[$row['catid']] = array("pid" => $row['catparent'], "name" =>  $row['catname']);   
    }

    //createTree($arrayCategories, 0);
    function createTree($array, $currentParent, $currLevel = 0, $prevLevel = -1) 
    {
      foreach ($array as $categoryId => $category) 
      {
        if ($currentParent == $category['pid']) 
        {                       
            if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) echo " <ul> "; 
            if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo " </li> ";
            echo '<li id="'.$categoryId.'" onclick=child(this.id);><span>'.$category['name'].'</span>';
            if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) { $prevLevel = $currLevel; }
            $currLevel++; 
            createTree ($array, $categoryId, $currLevel, $prevLevel);
            $currLevel--;               
        }   
      }
      if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo " </li>  </ul> ";
    }   
?>
<div id="content" class="general-style1">
<?php
   if($result->num_rows!=0)
   {
  ?>
  <ul>
      <li id="0" class="root"><span>Categories</span>
      <?php createTree($arrayCategories, 0); ?>
  </li>
  </ul>
  <?php
    }
  }
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: A combobox is a UI control that is a combination (hence the name) of a drop down menu (which is what you get with a select in HTML) and a text input (an input of type text). HTML doesn't have any native controls that are represented as comboboxes. To get one, you have to  construct with a pile of JavaScript. Alternatively, you might have meant "a select element". Which are you asking about?

Comment: Sorr for the wrong name. Call it then Dropdown boxes

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, but you need to modify field names in cat_tree_array.

```
function cat_tree_array($items) {
    $childs = array();
    foreach ($items as &$item) {
        $item = (array) $item;
        $childs[$item['id_parent']][] = &$item;
    }
    unset($item);

    foreach ($items as &$item) {
        $item = (array) $item;
        if (isset($childs[$item['id']])) {
            $item['_subs'] = $childs[$item['id']];
        }
    }
    return $childs[0];
}
```

Usage:

```
<?
// items: all data that you fetch from db (so just an array)
// e.g
// $qry = mysql_query("select * from categorys");
// while ($fch = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) $items[] = $fch;
$tree = cat_tree_array($items); 
?>
```

HTML List:

```
<ul>
<? foreach ($tree as $t): ?>
    <li><?=$t['category_name']?></li>
    <? if (!empty($t['_subs'])): ?>
        <ul>
            <? foreach ($t['_subs'] as $s): ?>
                <li><?=$s['category_name']?></li>
            <? endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <? endif; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

HTML Select:

```
<select>
<? foreach ($tree as $t): ?>
    <option><?=$t['category_name']?></option>
    <? if (!empty($t['_subs'])): ?>
        <optgroup>
            <? foreach ($t['_subs'] as $s): ?>
                <option><?=$s['category_name']?></option>
            <? endforeach; ?>
        </optgroup>
    <? endif; ?>
<? endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: This code uses an unordered list like the code I have allready. What I need is a dropdownbox with indention on the subcategories.

Comment: OK! See the last part of answer.

Comment: I'm trying it, but need your help with the array keys to match them to my array. Can idntify 'category_name: 'catname', 'id_parent': 'catparent', but '_subs', cat match to any of my keys. Can you help me with that "tranlation"?

Answer (score 0):

@qeremy

This is your code adapted (tryed to) my SQL:

```
<?php
  include '../lib/configuration.php';

  function cat_tree_array($items) {
      $childs = array();
      foreach ($items as &$item) {
          $item = (array) $item;
          $childs[$item['catparent']][] = &$item;
      }
      unset($item);

      foreach ($items as &$item) {
          $item = (array) $item;
          if (isset($childs[$item['id']])) {
              $item['catid'] = $childs[$item['id']];
          }
      }
      return $childs[0];
  }  

  $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $database);

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
  {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
  }

  $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
  if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) 
  {

  /* fetch associative array */
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  { 
    $tree = cat_tree_array($items);
  } 
  ?>

  <select>
  <?php foreach ($tree as $t): ?>
      <option><?php = $t['catname']?></option>
      <?php if (!empty($t['catid'])): ?>
          <optgroup>
              <?php foreach ($t['catid'] as $s): ?>
                  <option><?php = $s['catname']?></option>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
          </optgroup>
      <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
```

I get an error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in D:\Web Data\mydl\admin\test1.php on line 43

This is line 43:

```
  <option><?php = $t['catname']?></option>
```

Iºm not a PHP expert, but realy do not understand that code

Comment: You don't need to change `_subs` key, cos it's not related with your data stack. DO NOT TOUCH `_subs` key in second `foreach`. Just check it so `if(!empty($t['_subs']))` while you printing out. Also that line is wrong, change it to: `<?php echo $t['catname']; ?>` or `<?=$t['catname']?>`.

Comment: Does not work. Gives an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in D:\Web Data\mydl\admin\test1.php on line 52 which is the very last line